# Best practice to handle exceptions in GLUT functions

Tags: c, exception, glut

I'm following openGL tutorials from openglbook.com and trying to simulate a scenario when requested an OpenGL context is not available on the computer. My laptop opengl video driver version is 3.0 and i'm requesting 3.3. The goal is to gracefully recover from the error. Here is the code:

```
glutInitContextVersion(3, 3);
glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE,GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS);
glutInitWindowSize(CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);

WindowHandle = glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX);

if (WindowHandle < 1) {
    fprintf(
            stderr,
            "ERROR: Could not create a new rendering window.\n"
            );
    return -1;
}
```

The issue I have is my program breaks on the line:

```
WindowHandle = glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX);
```

and I can't even check for the return code as it seems that glutCreateWindow() simply does exit() on it's own. What is the best way to handle these types of situations in C?

Comment: Have you tried [`glGetError`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetError.xml) right after `glutInitContextVersion(3, 3);`? I can't find any documentation on glutInitContextVersion and glut is very old, so I'm not sure what kind of error checking it provides. It seems that you should be checking the results sooner than you are though.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem one time and I solved removing these lines of the code:

```
glutInitContextVersion(3, 3);
glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
```

(I was using freeglut though)